# Calling external webapi causes nullreference exception. This code works if its in project by itself

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have this code working in its own application. But if I run this code in the project that is going to finally end up in, I get an exception. Here is the stacktrace for the same.

An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.

Application ID: 28507bb0

Process ID: 14936

Exception: System.NullReferenceException

Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

StackTrace:    at System.Web.ThreadContext.AssociateWithCurrentThread(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
   at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallbackPossiblyUnderLock(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.CallCallback(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Web.LegacyAspNetSynchronizationContext.Post(SendOrPostCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.PostAction(Object state)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.RunCallback(ContextCallback callback, Object state, Task& currentTask)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.AwaitTaskContinuation.b__1(Object s)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

The old app was .net 4.0 and I have opened it in VS 2012 and upgraded each of the project in that solution to 4.5. Nothing has changed that error.

Any ideas why the code works on its own but throws this stacktrace in the other application?

```
    private async Task<IList<InventoryItem>> GetPartsInfoAsync(string SearchText)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        IList<InventoryItem> partList = new List<InventoryItem>();
        string address = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseUrl"] + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PartsSearch"] + "?login=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Login"] + "&apikey=" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiKey"] + "&search_token=" + SearchText + "&useExact=true";

        try
        {
            HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(address); 
            responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            //client.Timeout = System.TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50);

            Parts.RootObject ArrowPartData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parts.RootObject>(await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            if (ArrowPartData != null)
            {

            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException requestException)
        {
                        throw requestException;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return partList;
    }
```

Comment: This looks very similar to your last question.

Comment: @gunr2171 - It is, but no one is taking a hold off and I wasnt sure if anyone can see my previous question. And also I wanted to clarify more so that I can get an answer based on clarity and not confusion.

Comment: Only you can take it off "on hold" by editing your post to so it fits the rules of this site. You can then add more information to help clarify it.

Comment: @gunr2171 I did change and clarify my post and posted more information that was requested so my question could be more clearer. Is there anything else I need to do to get it off hold?

Comment: read for more information: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/213671

Comment: It looks like your code crashes somewhere in the async plumbing code when you run it in the project it will end up in. Have you tried making the code synchronous? Does the same thing happen if you remove the async Task from your method signature and change the client.GetAsync to client.Get. Does it still crash? Is there anything about the "project that it will end up in" that you could share? What could be different between your test project and the final project? Your stack trace seems to be from an event log? Is the final project some service? These things may give some clues

Comment: @OlavNybø -- I tried calling this same piece of code from a clean page ( none of the old code, just a button and text box) and it ran fine. Now I am guessing that the code is failing due to something on the page. But I am wondering what would cause this GetAysnc to fail? Is there anything that would cause this call to fail?

Comment: So I was able to pinpoint the issue but not sure why it happens. I have a js file on the page and that js file has a ajax function which will be called once someone clicks on a link. So now I have async call which runs at the start of the page and ajax call which runs when you click on a certain link. If I comment out that ajax call I have everything running. Any reason why jQuery ajax call might interfere with async calls?

Comment: Is it a web forms Application or an MVC Application? If web forms, what event handler do you call the async method from?

Comment: It is web form applications. From my preliminary investigation where I tried eliminating code from the page, I noticed that await client.GetAsync(address) is what takes a lot of time.

I have database calls which will get the results from local database, integrate the data from this REST call. Because the REST call takes a lot of time everything related to the data causes the error. I put the REST call in PageLoad_Complete and everything was fine.